# using Google Maps bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I have an app that is using the Google maps bundle. The interface is defined in the STMapView.h file:

```
@interface STMapView : GMSMapView
```

I am trying to use my STMapView.m View to make my markers react to clicking, so I put this function in it:

```
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    NSLog(@"WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING");
    return YES;
}
```

However, the markers only show their info when I click on them, the didTapMarker function is never used because the NSLog is not printing to the output.  Do I need to define the function elsewhere?
Also, once I get the function responding to clicking, how to I make it respond with a little popup view or new view passing in the info of the marker?

UPDATE:

STMapView.h

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
@interface STMapView : GMSMapView
- (void) updateShuttlesOnMap:(NSMutableData *) shuttleData;
@end
```

STMapView.m

```
#import "STMapView.h"
#import "STShuttleMarker.h"
#import "STNetworkManager.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface STMapView()

// This is where we will hold all our shuttles
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *shuttleMarkers;

// Used privately to add the shuttle stop icons to the map
- (void) addShuttleStopsToMap;
@end
@implementation STMapView

// Perform initial map setup as a View
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {   
  // First run the super-class init
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];  
  // Then do our setup if we actually have an object
  if (self) {  
    // Start with room for 6 shuttles. Unsure if initial capacity helps performance or not.
    self.shuttleMarkers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:6];     
    // We will handle the location stuff ourself.
    self.myLocationEnabled = NO;     
    // Nice visuals
    self.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;     
    // Move it to an initial location
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:33.613341
                                                            longitude:-84.496
                                                                 zoom:16.5];
    self.camera = camera;   
    //[self addShuttleStopsToMap];
    [self addPickupToMap];
  }
 return self;
}
```

The Markers are added later on in a separate function in the .m file.  Here is a little chunk of that code:

```
for (NSDictionary *shuttleStopMarker in shuttleStops) {
        // Setup a set of coordinates to use for the marker
        double mlat  = [(NSNumber *)[shuttleStopMarker objectForKey:@"lat" ] doubleValue];
        double mlong = [(NSNumber *)[shuttleStopMarker objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D markerLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mlat, mlong);

        // Grab the meta data to use for the marker
        NSString *shuttleStopName = (NSString *)[shuttleStopMarker objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *shuttleStopDescription = (NSString *)[shuttleStopMarker   objectForKey:@"description"];

        // Create this marker with a position, title, and snippet/description
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition: markerLocation];
        marker.title = shuttleStopName;
        marker.snippet = shuttleStopDescription;
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PassengerImage"];
        //[marker.map setSelectedMarker:marker];
        // Now add it to the map.
        marker.map = self;
    }
```

Comment: How did you assign a delegate to `STMapView`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong The STMapView functions as a regular UIView element with a few specific enhancements.

Comment: @AnthonyKong What exactly do you mean? Like what does my STViewController look like?

Comment: I am referring to this property: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a28cb659078228366db3b120a704e30c4 How did you set it? Did you set it?

Comment: Oh yes in the STViewController.h I have     '@interface STViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> '    Do I need to delegate the map in the STMapVew.h?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Also, thank you for the help, Objective C can really get the best of me sometimes

Comment: Given you have provided so little information and it seems like you do not know much about the concept of delegate, I suggest you to do more research and self-study on this subject. There are plenty of STMapView sample codes out there.

Comment: @Becksters can you provide the STMapView.h file and the initialisation of mapview in STMapView.m file? Also,explain me a little more what do you want to do with the markers to help you if i can.

Comment: @AnthonyKong done.  The whole app in itself basically tracks buses and shows them on the map.  The markers serve as the bus stops.

Comment: @hoya21 if I make your changes, the rest of my code breaks.

Comment: @Becksters Obviously if you use my code you have to change a little of the remaining code to be consistent with this.This is because STMapView in my project is an UIViewController and not a GSMapView. Also check the link that i added to my answer.

Comment: @hoya21 you were right I did need to add the <GMSMapViewDelegate>  but the function still does not work... but it should be able to because everything else about the markers work, even though I'm using 'interface STMapView : GMSMapView '

Comment: @hoya21 could I not just use self instead? I've been using that for everything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to add this to STMapView.h file

```
@interface STMapView:UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

In STMapView.m file:

```
@interface STMapView () {
   GMSMapView *mapView_;
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad you have to initialise your map like this:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:36.4349631
                                                        longitude:28.21748290000005
                                                             zoom:9];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.delegate = self;
self.view = mapView_;
```

And add a marker everywhere you want like this:

```
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:first1];
    marker.title=first.title;
    marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hist.png"];
    marker.map = mapView_;
```

It works properly for me and didTapMarker is called too.

Also check this function if you want to add some functionality to when the window of the marker is tapped.

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)  marker
{


}
```

Also check this for more documentation:

[GMSMapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map)